Use libnm or popen(nmcli) to configure network programmatically?
We have a system where we need the user to be able to permanently change the network settings from the interface (via our C code), that used to be achieved by generating a new dhcpcd.conf file and then restarting the network but now that doesn't exist - dhcpcd has gone and Network manager (nmcli / libnm) are the new thing.
I've looked into libnm but there seem to be very few examples out there and it's quite complex, the "lazy" option would be to use popen() to interact with nmcli but that feels a bit hacky.
So - should I bite the bullet and use libnm calls, or is the popen method perfectly acceptable? Or is there some third way that I've missed?

I think both are viable, sensible options; nmcli's man page even says:

Typical uses include:

Scripts: Utilize NetworkManager via nmcli instead of managing network connections manually.  nmcli supports a terse output format which is better suited for script processing.


So, being called externally is definitely a design goal, and with --terse you will get output that the maintainers put thought into keeping stable for usage by computer programs parsing it.
I think libnm mostly makes more sense if

your C program already uses GObject anyways, and
you don't want to directly handle D-Bus calls yourself, but
also don't want to work very abstracted from the D-Bus API of NetworkManager.

Since the operations you describe are "large" anyways, meaning that the things they cause will take multiple milliseconds, maybe even seconds, the overhead of a single popen (which internally creates pipes, forks, invokes a shell, and tells the shell to execute a command) is really insignificant.
So, I'd go for invoking nmcli --terse {subcommand} from your C program. Whether you do that via the simple
FILE* output = popen("nmcli --terse foobar", "r");

which involves spawning a shell, or, more advanced, but maybe advantageous if you want to do things like use nmcli connection monitor,
char* args[] = {"nmcli", "--terse", "foobar"};
char* nmcli_path = "/usr/bin/nmcli";
struct io_pipe {
  int read_end;
  int write_end;
};
struct io_pipe pipe_fd;

int success = pipe(&pipe_fd); // check success >= 0!
int child_pid = fork();       // check new_pid >= 0!
if(child_pid > 0) {           // we're the parent!
  close(pipe_fd.write_end);   // we don't need the write end
  /* Do whatever you would have done with the FILE* coming out of popen here,
   * e.g., 
   * fd_set watched_fds;
   * FD_ZERO(&watched_fds);
   * FD_SET(io_pipe.read_end, &watched_fds);
   * fcntl(io_pipe.read_end, O_NONBLOCK);
   * struct timeval timeout = {.tv_sec = 5, .tv_usec = 0};
   * char* buffer = NULL;
   * while(select(1,            // how many file descriptors?
                  &watched_fds, // which read descriptors
                  NULL, NULL,   // which write, exception descriptors
                  timeout       // timeval specifying timeout.
                 )) {
   *   if(!buffer) {
   *     buffer = malloc(4096);
   *   }
   *   int howmuch = read(pipe_fd.read_end, buffer, 4096);
   *   // Do clever stuff with the things you read!
   * }
   * free(buffer);
   */
  int wstatus;
  waitpid(child_pid, &wstatus, 0); 
  /* see `man 2 wait` for what you can do with wstatus */
} else {                      // we're the child!
  close(pipe_fd.read_end);    // we don't need the read end
                              // we connect our stdout to the write end:
  dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, pipe_fd.write_end);
  execv(nmcli_path, args);    // we replace ourselves with nmcli 
}

is fully up to you.
